# Re-render a Jekyll document in :site post_render hook

Tags: jekyll

I'm currently working on a Jekyll plugin that transforms the output HTML in the `post_render` hook of `:documents`. I would like to provide access to some information derived from the result of these transformations via a Liquid tag. This is obviously problematic, since I can only be sure that all transformations have been executed when the `post_render` hook of `:site` is called, but at that point Liquid tags have already been evaluated.

This leads to my question: Can a Jekyll plugin trigger a "re-rendering" of a page after `post_render` has fired, so that Liquid tags that were not available when the page was first rendered are then populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading parts of the Jekyll source code ([`site.rb`](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/site.rb) and [`renderer.rb`](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb)), I have learned how to implement such a "two-stage" plugin.

Since the initial file contents are overwritten during the rendering process, they have to be stored explicitly:

```ruby
Jekyll::Hooks.register [:documents, :pages], :pre_render do |doc|
  Jekyll::MyPlugin.unrendered_docs[doc.relative_path] = doc.content
end
```

After the site has been rendered, the document `doc` can then be re-rendered as follows:

```ruby
Jekyll::Hooks.register :site, :post_render do |site, payload|
  ...
  doc.content = Jekyll::MyPlugin.unrendered_docs[doc.relative_path]
  doc.output = Jekyll::Renderer.new(site, doc, payload).run()
  doc.trigger_hooks(:post_render)
  ...
end
```